# Vaadin 14 how to move the vaadin servlet to a different URL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a pretty basic vaadin application running.  The application is spring-boot backed and I defined some rest API.

I've added OpenAPI documentation using org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.4, which worked perfectly before adding vaadin.

After adding the vaadin dependencies as shown in the vaadin spring-boot tutorial, and creating a view (which works), the swagger UI is no longer reachable.

It seems to me that vaadin completely takes over all web requests.  Digging deeper, I've found that vaadin registers a new servlet and catches all requests.

I don't find any docs on how to configure this -- I'd expect that one could configure vaadin such that it serves UI from a different path, say `/ui` or similar.

I've tried to set

```
vaadin:
   url-mapping: "/ui/*"
```

in my `application.yaml` -- but this results in blank pages (no errors) for my vaadin views,
and the vaadin servlet does still take over `/`.

I use spring.boot `2.3.2.RELEASE`, vaadin `14.3.1`.

Comment: As noted below -- I've since debugged this further.  It seems to me that vaadin WebJar servlet intercepts all requests and does some logic to decide if a particular request targets a WebJar dependency of vaadin.

The logic used -- which I don't fully understand yet -- decides purely on the request's path.  Unfortunately this interferes with the  `springdoc` spring configuration which registers its own webinars for the swagger UI.  The configuration is done, but requests do not reach the `springdoc` code.

Comment: Se also more discussion on this topic in the [vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18400081/vaadin-14-spring-boot-vaadin-takes-over-all-web-requests-how-to-confi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value to override is (note the camelCase instead of the kebab-case):

```yaml
vaadin:
  urlMapping: /ui/*
```

Using the kebab-case did (does) **not** work.  As expected, this is a bug.  See https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/637

From the docs at the point of time:

> You can set properties for Spring Boot in your `application.properties` file.
>
> Example: Setting Spring URL mapping in `application.properties`.
>
> ```
> vaadin.urlMapping=/my_mapping/*
> ```
>
> By default, URL mapping is `/*`.
>
> > An additional servlet, such as `/my_mapping/*`, is required to handle the frontend resources for non-root servlets. The servlet can be defined in your application class. See this [Application class](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaadin/flow-and-components-documentation/master/tutorial-servlet-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/vaadin/tutorial/spring/Application.java) for a example.
>
> ---
>
> Source: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-configuration.html#using-spring-boot-properties

Comment: camel case and kebab case are interpolated correctly by spring-boot externalised configuration.  That's not the issue.  Also, I *do* see changes when I add that configuration.

Comment: The problem is related to vaadin's WebJar Servlet intercepting requests.   Still need to debug more but this is not a configuration problem.

Comment: Yes -- indeed.  This is baffling to me, but yes.

Comment: Same here - i have not tried to find the culprit, but my guess is some hackery to get the value via the spring-way while this feature is already there in the core.  I consider it a bug.

Comment: It seems to be related to this bug https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/637 It seems that a fix was merged to 14.0.2 11 days ago: https://github.com/vaadin/spring/commit/f428adff04f1d4c180ea1d133f8d6b9e174657c4

Comment: Correction: The bug was in the spring integration 4.0.1 and appears to be fixed in 4.0.2.  It's not in the change log, however: https://github.com/vaadin/spring/releases/tag/14.0.2

Comment: The fix is apparently only for vaadin 17.

Comment: Just tested -- vaadin 14.3.5 still has this bug.